# clip-path for display an div below another div

Tags: css, clip-path

I wish display a div below another div with clip-path, but the result is a little strange.

[DEMO CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygOeJR)

```
clip-path: polygon(0 285px, 30px 300px, 0 315px);
```

If you comment the clip-path CSS, the block display normally.

But, I would like to achieve this. In my image example, the red square is below to green square.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood what you wanted, here's a working example. I had to restructure your code a tiny bit. I applied the clipping to your red div, the one with the image. Then I drew the clipping mask using percentages, including the entire rectangle, not just the triangle:

```
.left {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: green;
    height: 600px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 285px, 110% 300px, 100% 315px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 285px, 110% 300px, 100% 315px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    padding: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdNymZ